# Is it correct to use short syntax when initializing NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Usually when we want to initialize `NSMutableArray` we use:

```
NSMutableArray *mArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
```

But, is it correct to use syntax like:

```
NSMutableArray *mArr = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"].mutableCopy;
```

I understand, that it will work a couple of nanoseconds longer. But I think the second way to be way more readable and  I'm ready to sacrifice those nanoseconds.

Is it ok, to use this kind of construction? Does ARC clean that unused NSArray, that I'm using to get a mutable copy? Isn't it going to be a leak?

Comment: Note that it's probably something that should be avoided if you're doing thousands of them in a short period, not so much because of the CPU time but the creation of so many extra objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I think the second way to be way more readable

Personally, I find it more confusing, and even more confusing since you are using `mutableCopy` as if it was a property. Correct, correct, but totally misleading IMHO.

Why not just take advantage of **inheritance?**

```
NSMutableArray *ma = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", nil];
```

<sub>Sometimes collections which are mutable by default would be of more use. * sigh *</sub>

Comment: Agreed.  In the apps that I work on we tend to have interfaces return mutable arrays, since that's what get's created anyway, and since it's often useful to have them mutable.  (And I can't recall a single case, in 4 years of iOS programming, where having a mutable array led to an error that a non-mutable one would have prevented.)

Comment: @HotLicks Sure. Most scripting languages have mutable collections only. **It's not about semantical errors, though.** Apple's argument for collections defaulting to immutability is performance. When one copies a lot of arrays, it matters if `copy` is implemented using a simple `retain` or a whole loop copying all members. I must admit, though, that I couldn't find a representative example for this either.

Comment: Except that, in "real life", copying only occurs when one wants either a 'snapshot" copy of a mutable array or a mutable copy of a non-mutable array.  Making a non-mutable copy of a non-mutable array is rarely done.  (I mentioned errors since that's often given as a reason for wanting non-mutable data.)

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly, that's what I meant by "I couldn't find a representative example for this".

Comment: The obvious point where this is introduced is copy-on-set accessors. In that case, many immutable-copy-of-immutable objects are performed (although no allocation may not necessarily be performed if immutable->immutable). The properties for such types should be `copy`. It's also useful because an API should generally avoid relying on where its data is coming from. Even immutable types should return new instances when copied in some scenarios (e.g. the type refers to backing memory it does not own). The mutability distinction is very important, and (IMO) it was very smart to use in Cocoa's case…

Comment: …given the absence of const-qualification for Objective-C types.

Comment: @justin definitely, that's a good example, but - as you say - permitting the `const`-qualification of properties would have been a better decision, in my opinion.

Comment: @H2CO3 const-qualification could have been great in objc. today's tools are good enough that it could be added (without much pain), and supported with derivation. i'd be surprised if it happened, as anything i have seen which affects dynamic method lookup (or its complexity) has received much mixed favor (e.g. namespacing). it's just kinda hard to introduce when the language is so dynamic, given the decades of published libraries. the other thing is, `const` doesn't mean much to an object which holds (mostly) pointers. if const-ness were added in theory, i'd favor const transitivity.

Comment: @H2CO3 but the problem with that is nothing using present day Cocoa libraries could be const-transitive -- it would have to be a whole new set of APIs.

Comment: @justin Yeah, unfortunately... "it's hard to teach an old dog new tricks", not exactly in this sense, but you get it...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's ok to initialize your mutable array that way, if you are willing (as you indicated) to pay the performance cost.  ARC will clean everything up appropriately.  It won't leak.

Comment: Apple uses it this way in some code examples, so yes - it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use arrayWithArray.

```
NSMutableArray *foo = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"one", @"two", @"three"]];
```

Comment: Might as well use arrayWithObjects  as H2CO3 illustrates.

Comment: He said he found the @[] syntax to be more readable, so I gave him an option that used that.  And you don't need that final nil, which I find aesthetically unpleasant.  :)